# SQL Query returning only one record

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am attempting to run a simple SQL stored procedure query, but am getting only 1 record returned. Anyone know what the issue is?

```
Alter PROCEDURE spGetRecruiterList
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    DECLARE @TitleID as int
    set @TitleID = (Select TitleID from tblJobTitle where JobTitle = 'Recruiter')
    Print @TitleID

    Select p.PersonID, p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.LastName
    from tblPerson p
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblLinkTitleToPerson tp 
    ON p.PersonID = tp.PersonID 
    WHERE tp.PersonID = @TitleID
    Order By p.LastName
END
GO
```

Comment: I think that it's normal, because PersonID is a primary key. `WHERE tp.PersonID = @TitleID` will return only one result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 WHERE tp.PersonID = @TitleID
```

Should be

```
 WHERE tp.TitleID = @TitleID
```

(probably!)

Comment: it's almost like you are watching me :-0

Comment: @Csharp - Not sure what to make of that comment! Does that mean the issue is now resolved?

Comment: yes, thanks. However, system wont allow me to accept the answer for another 4 minutes :-(